# How to check that package is available to install?

Tags: freebsd

How to check that package givent by name exactly is available to install?

Some packages may be not available when install packages by list:

```
pkg install some packages ... ruby-gems
```

> No packages available to install matching 'ruby-gems' have been found in the repositories

The `pkg info` show info only for installed packages:

```
pkg info ruby23-gems
```

> pkg: No package(s) matching ruby23-gems

Now install and check info:

```
pkg install ruby23-gems
pkg info ruby23-gems
```

> ruby23-gems-2.6.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `pkg search` have appropriate args:

```
pkg search -S name --exact ruby23-gems
```

Where:

- `-S name` - specify the field to search the repository catalogue on
- `--exact` - pattern should be an exact match against the search field